# How do I upgrade the JSF API in GlassFish?

Tags: jsf, glassfish, glassfish-3

I [downloaded](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html) binary which has `javax.faces-2.1.13` as the latest binary release. I want to upgrade my GlassFish JSF library but it has `jsf-api-jar` and other impl. How do I update and where do I download the jars?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just replace *both* `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` in the Glassfish `/modules` folder by the single `javax.faces.jar` file.

Since Mojarra 2.1.6 the build system has been changed to comply Java EE Maven rules, see also [issue 2028](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2028). This resulted in the API and impl being merged into a single JAR file.

Comment: Should I delete those jar in Glassfish and add javax.faces.jar  ? That's it not configuration?

Comment: Surely. You don't want to have the older version hanging around conflicting the newer version, right? If you don't have full admin control over the server, then an alternative is to place the new JAR in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib` and configure `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file to tell Glassfish to use it instead.

Comment: what about jsftemplating and jsfconnector?

Comment: They are not part of standard JSF. As answered, just replace the API/impl JAR files by the single new JAR file. Please do it and report any problems instead of continuing asking irrelevant questions before ever having performed the upgrade.

Comment: I did that now IDE shows error that like FacesContext is not present. import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage; has failed

Comment: In the future please tell that directly. As to the problem, have you rebuilt the project and retargeted the server?

Comment: I can't built the project as it shows error.. retargeted the server means?

Comment: Sorry, this is beyond me. Try restarting the IDE. Try removing/adding the server in the IDE. Try removing/adding the server in the web project.

Comment: I also had this problem with NetBeans7.1. Removing/adding the server did not help. I had deleted both osgi-cache and NetBeans ~/.netbeans/7.1/var/cache (on Mac OS X). NetBeans7.1 stubbornly refuses to show javax.faces.jar under the Glassfish server libs and I still get import errors.

Comment: Related/(near duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715314/jsf-how-upgrade-to-mojarra-2-1-21-in-netbeans7-1-just-sub-jsf-api-jar-and-jsf-i

Comment: Thought I had found the solution here https://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2011/09/26/try-out-mojarra-220-snapshot?force=714, says replace references to jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar with javax.faces.jar in /domain/domain1/config/default-web.xml and /lib/templates/default-web.xml, but after multiple cache cleans, restart, remove/add server in Netbeans7.1 it sill does not see javax.faces.jar

Answer (score 0):

if you having some issues after replacing faces files in glassfish/modules folder, like non-compatibility of you framework version with jsf 2.2,2.3 and etc (for example "icefaces 4.1.1 error 200 during update: javax.faces.viewstate not found") or some unexpected behaviour - dont forget to clean glassfish/domains/somedomain/osgi-cache