# jsf 2.2 not supported on glassfish 3.1.2?

Tags: jsf, glassfish

Is jsf 2.2 not supported on glassfish 3.1.2?

My viewActions are not being invoked and some simple things do not behave same way as supposed with 2.1.23. So i am not sure about filing issues for 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By updating jar file some feature is supported. But, some of the feature. e.g. JSON processing is not supported. Use Glassfish 4.0 for best support.

Comment: Is there a list what is supported on older glassfish versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually update the .jar file located at the Glassfish's /modules directory.

More information: [How do I upgrade the JSF API in GlassFish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792222/how-do-i-upgrade-glassfish-jsf-api)